# Combining 3 sentences

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, sentence, relative-clauses, syntactic-analysis

I am struggling to combine following 3 sentences for a one sentence. I am doubted how to do it. Any suggestions please.

> a) Most of the above methods often rely on the crown height model
>   (CHM)
>
> b) Seek local maxima based on the CHM model
>
> c) Local maxima are the peak positions of the CHM

Comment: Why do you want to combine these sentences? Is it an exercise, are or you trying to make your writing less clear?

Comment: While I think this constitutes proof-reading, My question is about the sense of "following" in (b).  Are you saying that after performing one of the above methods, the next step is to seek the local maxima, or that the above methods entail seeking the local maxima. This would change how the sentences could be joined.

Comment: Given what I'm guessing is your answer to my question above, I'd say something like: *At the heart of most of the methods above is the use of the Crown Height Model in the determination of the peak positions, or local maxima.*

Comment: @Dear all, thanks for the efforts...i think you have been misguided by my original post.. so i am changing it as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly that the final “deliverable” sought from the models is the *local maxima*, I think you mean:

> Most of these models rely on the Crown Height Model: CHM peak positions provide the local maxima.

OR

> Most of these models rely on the Crown Height Model, deriving local maxima from CHM peak positions.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few small changes are required:

> **Most of the above methods often rely on *{using / applying [CHOOSE ONE]}* the crown height model (CHM) followed by seeking the local maxima, which is the peak position of the CHM.**

While I'm not a big fan of *applying* or *followed by*, they're the norm in academic prose, and I'm not getting paid to revise this, so this is good enough to pass muster with most journal editors and reviewers.

Comment: There's something wrong with this ... even for academic prose. It seems to say that the above methods rely on using the crown height model, and that the use of the crown height model is followed by seeking the local maxima. I don't think this is correct, since *using* a model followed by seeking the local maxima in the model doesn't seem likely to me. Maybe *constructing* the model, but I don't really know what the OP wants to say.

Comment: Also, *maxima* is plural, so it should be "the local maxima, which are the peak positions ..."

Comment: @Dear all, thanks for the efforts...actually what i want to say is: Most of the above methods often rely on the crown height model (CHM) and that CHM model is used to find local maxima. local maxima are the peak points of the CHM.

Comment: @Bill Franke: But if i can say this correctly, it is useful for me to learn academic writing styles. and i thought viewers have been misguided by me. So i changed the post. thanks